# How can I solve - Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Subscription'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wrote PUT and DELETE methods inside their functions ("editForm" and "deleteForm" respectively).

I wanted to display `setAlert()` function after each request successfully completes. therefore, I used `.then()` method and it works perfectly inside `editForm` function as you can see it below.

but when I do the same for `deleteForm`, `.then()` method does not works, because 
it says: " Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Subscription' ". So how can I solve this?

Here is my component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormService } from './forms.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { alert } from './alert';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})


export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  alert: alert;
  id: any;
  posts: any;

  constructor(public formService: FormService ,private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.alert = new alert();

    this.posts = this.formService.getForms(this.id).subscribe(
      (forms: any) => {
        this.formService.form = forms[0];
      }
    );
  }

  editPost() {
    this.formService.editForm().then((res:any) => {
      this.formService.alert.setAlert("Post has been successfully saved !");
    })
  }

  deletePost() {
    this.formService.deleteForm().subscribe(
      data  => {
        console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);
      },
      error  => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      }
    ).then(() => {
      this.formService.alert.setAlert("Post has been successfully deleted !");
    })
  }

}
```

Here is my service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { form } from './form-interface';
import { alert } from './alert';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
}) 

export class FormService {

  formsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  form: form = {
      id: 0,
      userId: 0,
      title: '',
      body: ''
  };
  alert: alert;


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
      this.alert = new alert();
    }

    getForms(id) {
            return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
            + "?id=" + id)
    }

    editForm() {
        return fetch(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.form.id, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.form),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
    }

    deleteForm() {
        return this.http.delete(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.form.id);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `editform` method uses JavaScript `fetch` api to call the service, which returns the promise so `then` method works there. In `deleteForm` method, you are making a service call using angular `HttpClient` which returns observable. instead of using `then` you should use `subscribe` method

```
deleteForm() {
        return this.http.delete(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.form.id);
}
```

In your component.ts

```
 deletePost() {
    this.formService.deleteForm().subscribe(
      data  => {
        console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);
        this.formService.alert.setAlert("Post has been successfully deleted !");
      },
      error  => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Previously I had exactly like that. but there is one issue with such way. if something goes wrong, it still displays the success message. but in the case of .then(), it will only run if the request is completed successfully.

Comment: what you actually mean by something goes wrong, if a http error happens then error method inside the subscribe will gets called? whats your issue?

Answer (score 0):

because http returns observable not promise. Use .subscribe here.It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use message when you get a proper response while you get the response in subscribe method and call alert into it
Like below

```
deletePost() {
this.formService.deleteForm().subscribe(
  data  => {
    console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);
    this.formService.alert.setAlert("Post has been successfully deleted !");
  },
  error  => {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }
))
```

}

Comment: Previously I had exactly like that. but there is one issue with such way. if something goes wrong, it still displays the success message. but in the case of .then(), it will only run if the request is completed successfully.

Comment: You can use if confition that while you are getting response success than and then display it